# Magnetic Field of a Magnetic Dipole (equatorial position)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, integration, dipole-moment

Suppose that we have a current carrying circular loop, with radius $a$. At large distance $r \gg a$ from centre of loop, this loop acts as a magnetic dipole. We need to find magnetic field of loop at distance $r$, in the same plane as the loop (ie equatorial position.)

I first began without any approximations, using sine and cosine laws and **biot savart** law, and integral came out to be overwhelmingly complex.

Then I started with some approximations on $r$, and used biot savart law to reach to following integral:

$$\dfrac{\mu_o ia}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{\cos (\theta)\ d \theta}{\left(r-{a}\cos\theta\right)^2}$$

[image]

Please can someone give a proper approach to get to the result? Using approximations seems to be the only way, but I can't get close to the correct set of approximations.

The **correct answer** was given as  $|\vec{B}|=\dfrac{\mu_0 m}{4\pi r^3}$, but they used **magnetic charges**, which I don't want to use presently. Note that here $m$ = magnetic moment, which is $\pi a^2 i$

Comment: Derivation here http://www.physicsinsights.org/dipole_field_1.html or here http://www.physicspages.com/2013/04/11/magnetic-dipole/

Comment: @farcher Thankyou, but first link uses magnetic charge, and second link is way too advanced for me as it speaks of higher mathematical topics, nevertheless very useful link both of them.

Comment: Here is a website where, via more "advanced" (magnetic vector potential) methods, the author has found the off axis magnetic field. It just shows how difficult the task is but perhaps by looking at the results of his computations you can make suitable approximation to answer your question? http://www.grant-trebbin.com/2012/04/off-axis-magnetic-field-of-circular.html